# How can I get a single product in my array when adding to shopping cart?

Tags: javascript, html, api, shopping-cart

The problems I'm having right now is that when I press any "buy" button it adds the whole array to my shopping cart. I would like to only add the product that I press. I've been stuck for hours and I cant seem to find what I am supposed to do. Anyone got any tips?

This is what happens now when I press the buy button... (GIF) https://gyazo.com/ea20d377adc802782dcf88079fd209b5

My JS:

```
const shopContainer = document.querySelector(".shop-content");

let productTitle;
let productDescription;
let productImage;
let productPrice;
let productCategory;
let productId;
let productKey = [];
let productArray = [];

let output = "";

const url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";

let data = fetch(url)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      productTitle = data[i].title;
      productDescription = data[i].description;
      productImage = data[i].image;
      productPrice = data[i].price;
      productCategory = data[i].category;
      productId = data[i].id;
      productArray[i] = [
        productTitle,
        productDescription,
        productImage,
        productPrice,
        productCategory,
        productId,
      ];
      productKey[i] = data[i].id;
      localStorage.setItem(productKey[i], JSON.stringify(productArray[i]));
    }
    showApi();
    console.log(productArray)
  });

console.log(localStorage)

function showApi() {
  for (let i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {
    output += `
              <div class="product-box">
              <img class="product" src="${productArray[i][2]}" alt="product image">
              <h2 class="product-title">${productArray[i][0]}</h2>
                  <div class="bottom-box">
                  <span class="price">${productArray[i][3]}$</span>
                  <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag add-cart' id="${i}" onclick="returnKey()"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
          `;
  }
  shopContainer.innerHTML = output;
  console.log(productArray);
};

let knapp = document.getElementsByClassName("bx bx-shopping-bag");

console.log(knapp);

let inputCart = document.querySelector(".inputCart")

function returnKey() {
  if (localStorage.length !== 0){
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key){
    object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))
    completeProduct = (object)

    let cartPrice = document.createElement("p");
    let cartTitle = document.createElement("p");
    let cartImage = document.createElement("img");
    inputCart.appendChild(cartPrice);
    inputCart.appendChild(cartImage);
    inputCart.appendChild(cartTitle);
    
    cartTitle.setAttribute("class", "cart-title")
    cartImage.setAttribute("src", completeProduct[2]);
    cartImage.setAttribute("width", "75");
    cartImage.setAttribute("height", "75");

    cartTitle.innerHTML = completeProduct[0];
    cartPrice.innerHTML = ("$" + completeProduct[3]);
  })
  inputCart.innerHTML = cartTitle;
  }
};
```

I've tried searching on stackoverflow to find help and I've tried to use event.target but with zero sucess.

Comment: There's a lot of code here, can you reduce it to an [mre] per [ask]?

Comment: I cleared it now. I'm a beginner at coding so please feel free to tell me what to do if I'm not being clear enough :)

Comment: I belive its my function called returnkey(), thats wrong. But I dont really know what to implement.

Answer (score 0):

In the returnKey function you are looping over every element in the local storage and adding it to the cart. I think thats the reason why all products are added at once.
You can try passing the id of the product to returnKey(), and then filtering the localStorage first to get that product and only then add to cart.

```
<i class='bx bx-shopping-bag add-cart' id="${i}" onclick="returnKey(${id})"></i>
```

afterwards, in returnKey() make sure to filter the exact product from localStorage before adding it to the cart. 
(I would personally store the data received from the api in an Obj instead of localStorage. easier to manipulate and work with imo)
hope this helps!